# Array reduce not giving all the data

Tags: javascript

```js
let inputArr = [{
    "gender": "MALE",
    "name": "A",
    "age": 20
  },
  {
    "gender": "MALE",
    "name": "B",
    "age": 12
  },
  {
    "gender": "FEMALE",
    "name": "C",
    "age": 16
  },
  {
    "gender": "MALE",
    "name": "D",
    "age": 21
  },
  {
    "gender": "FEMALE",
    "name": "E",
    "age": 30
  }
]
console.log(JSON.stringify(inputArr.reduce((acc, ele) => {

  if (acc[ele["gender"]]) {
    acc[ele.gender].members.push(ele);
  } else {

    acc[ele["gender"]] = {
      members: []
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, {})))
```

I am trying to group users on the basis of gender ,using `Array.reduce` but the output is not showing all the records that are included in the array ,I am not able to understand the isssue here

Comment: In the `else` you're creating the key + value but you're not adding anything. So, you always omit the first value which will have a new key.

Comment: `acc[ele["gender"]] = { members: [ele] };`

Comment: thankyou @VLAZ .I made it work now

Answer (score 1):

Your reducer doesn't push the element when it encounter a gender for the first time, so the first user of each gender is missing from your result

```js
let inputArr = [{"gender": "MALE","name": "A","age": 20},{"gender": "MALE","name": "B","age": 12},{"gender": "FEMALE","name": "C","age": 16},{"gender": "MALE","name": "D","age": 21},{"gender": "FEMALE","name": "E","age": 30}]

console.log(JSON.stringify(inputArr.reduce((acc, ele) => {

  if (acc[ele["gender"]]) {
    acc[ele.gender].members.push(ele);
  } else {

    acc[ele["gender"]] = {
      members: [ele] // initialise the array with the current user
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, {})))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, but I don't recommend this if performance matter.

```js
let inputArr = [{
    "gender": "MALE",
    "name": "A",
    "age": 20
  },
  {
    "gender": "MALE",
    "name": "B",
    "age": 12
  },
  {
    "gender": "FEMALE",
    "name": "C",
    "age": 16
  },
  {
    "gender": "MALE",
    "name": "D",
    "age": 21
  },
  {
    "gender": "FEMALE",
    "name": "E",
    "age": 30
  }
]

function groupBy(array, field) {
  return array.reduce((acc, item) => ({
    ...acc,
    [item[field]]: [...acc[item[field]] || [], item]
  }), {})
}

console.log(groupBy(inputArr, "gender"))
```